# Can Reinstall macOS delete partitions?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, macbook, recovery-mode

I made an Ubuntu partition on Mac (rEFInd). I installed something that made me loose connection to Ubuntu, cannot login. Ubuntu cannot be fixed because I cannot get into recovery mood by holding down the shift key.

I therefore want to delete my Ubuntu partition and install a new Ubuntu. I tried to remove the disk partition using disk utility, but I cannot click on the minus button. I even tried in Mac recovery mode, still don't have access to change the Ubuntu partition.

Is it possible to delete all partitions on Mac by Reinstall macOS in recovery mode? 
I'm using MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Mid 2014)

Comment: I think this question is about mac, not about Ubuntu.

Comment: It's unclear (at least to me) what you are asking here. It's clear what you think the solution is. but the problem is not well defined IMHO. Assuming  you have no critical data on the Ubuntu partition, have you considered booting from Ubuntu live media and adjusting your partitioning scheme with the tools available there?